# Problems with rspec scope in before blocks

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've searched for an answer to this but I just can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. I have an api client test that looks like the following:

```
module MyTests
  describe '#update' do

    # using a before(:all) block for setup
    before(:all) do
      @client1 = Client.new
      @initial_payload_state = @client1.update.payload
    end

    context 'with a known starting payload' do
      # The payload is some nasty nested json so I grab an existing one
      # and then use a helper method to convert it to a full payload.
      # Then I update the client with the new payload. I'm using before(:each)
      # so I can get the client into this state for every test.
      before(:each) do
        @full_payload_state = helper_method(@initial_payload_state)
      end

      context 'alter_payload_1 works' do
        # now that I have the payload in its full state I'd like to alter it to
        # produce a certain output
        before(:all) do
          @new_payload_state = alter_payload_1(@full_payload_state)
        end

        # I now want to update the client with the altered payload and make sure
        # it has the same data. The request and response bodies are formatted slightly
        # differently in this case.
        it 'works' do
          @updated_payload_state = @client1.update(@new_payload_state)
          expect(payloads_equal?(@full_payload_state, @new_payload_state).to eq true
        end
      end

      context 'alter_payload_2 works' do
        before(:all) do
          @new_payload_state = alter_payload_2(@full_payload_state)
        end

        it 'works' do
          @updated_payload_state = @client1.update(@new_payload_state)
          expect(payloads_equal?(@full_payload_state, @new_payload_state).to eq true
        end
      end
```

In reality, my before block for setup is much longer, so I think it makes sense to keep it that way. I tried to use a before(:each) block so I could have the same known state to start each of the alter_payload contexts. The problem is that with this setup, I get a no method error for this line:

```
@new_payload_state = alter_payload_1(@full_payload_state)
```

suggesting that @full_payload_state is nil. I'm certain I've got something wrong with respect to scope, but I'm not sure why or how to fix it. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a scope issue with before(:all).

In general, it's wise to stop using before(:all) because it entangles your tests.

Replace your before(:all) lines with before(:each), and this will make each of your tests independent of the others. This will likely help you find your glitch.